# How to obtain return type double?

Tags: java, double, return-value

I have created a method which is supposed to return type double and here is my code

```
private void myMethod()  
{ 
    if(myArrayList.size() >= 2) 
    {
        Double  t = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1);
        Double  d = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-2); 
        Double result = ( t+ d  ) / 2 ;
        System.out.println("Average is: "+result);
    }
}
```

I change void to double   and just after system.out..... line i added return result but this gives an error!! Could you please tell me how exactly i can change this method so that i obtain a return type of double?

Comment: can you post your method?

Comment: Try shifting the return outside the `IF` statement 
OR return some value from `ELSE` statement

Comment: So certain variation of this code triggers an undisclosed error message... Too much info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum things up, all the previous answer are right, but lack some minor detail, like @dinesh707 says, you must be able to return on every method branch (unless an exception occurs). And also be sure to declare the result variable outside the decision/if block, and to declare that the method return a double, and you should go with the double primitive, not the boxed version.

so the code looks like:

```
private double myMethod() { 
double result=0; 
if(myArrayList.size() >= 2) { 
    double t = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1); 
    double d = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-2); 
    result = ( t+ d ) / 2 ; 
    System.out.println("Average is: "+result); 
} 
return result;
```

}

Comment: why the proposed double primitive instead the Double object?

Comment: @Arno Saxena well, this is pretty much a strait forward thing, primitives are much lighter than their boxed counter parts, and before java 1.5 there was no auto unboxing, so you can never be to sure your unoxing will always perform. And Josh Bloch, says so in his book, Effective Java second edition, in atem 49, page 221.

Answer (score 4):

every branch has to give a double as return if you change the type of the method to double. Thus your error is because only if the "if" will be entered there will be an double as return, but not if not!

```
private Double myMethod()  
{ 
    Double result = 0; // has to be initialised ...
    if(myArrayList.size() >= 2) 
    {
        Double  t = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1);
        Double  d = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-2); 
        result = ( t+ d  ) / 2 ;
        System.out.println("Average is: "+result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

I think your rerun was inside the if condition. So method is worried about what happens when if condition is not true. You need to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
private double myMethod()  
{   
    double result=0;
    if(myArrayList.size() >= 2) 
    {
        Double  t = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1);
        Double  d = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-2); 
        result = ( t+ d  ) / 2 ;
        System.out.println("Average is: "+result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Better, but please make sure to declare the return type accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return type of the method. A method must return a value of method type. if method is declared void then it means that method do not return any value.

```
private double myMethod()  
{ 
double result =0;
if(myArrayList.size() >= 2) 
{
    double  t = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1);
    double  d = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-2); 
    result = ( t+ d  ) / 2 ;
    System.out.println("Average is: "+result);
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: `result` is out of scope at the time of return.

Comment: Good, but make sure to put the result declaration outside of the decision block.